# change RegEx in filter_url for text field

Tags: uri, input-formats

I have nodes with text field containing URLs. The content is imported from XML file. The URLs are converted to links with drupals filter system, which works fine for most of the links but not all. I guess its the regex in filter_url function, but I can't figure it out.

Example URL:

```
http://example.net/2027/uc1.$b81009?urlappend=%3Bseq=7
```

is converted to

```
<a href="http://example.net/2027/uc1">http://example.net/2027/uc1</a>.$b81009?urlappend=%3Bseq=7
```

I'm not a php expert but I'm trying to fix this issue with a custom module. I copied the function `_filter_url` to mymodule.module, renamed it to `mymodule_filter_url`. Invoking `hook_filter_info_alter(&$info)` I change the process callback:

```
$info['filter_url']['process callback'] = 'mymodule_filter_url';
```

Now I have to find the regex expression, which stops the URL encoding right before the '.$'. I guess it's in one of these lines:

```
$trail = '[a-zA-Z0-9:%_+*~#&\[\]=/;?!\.,-]*[a-zA-Z0-9:%_+*~#&\[\]=/;-]';
$punctuation = '[\.,?!]*?';
```

But here I'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I got the answer. I added "\$" to the $trail RegEx pattern.

```
$trail = '[a-zA-Z0-9:%_+*~#&\[\]=/;?!\.,\-\$]*[a-zA-Z0-9:%_+*~#&\[\]=/;-]';
```

Are there any drawbacks with this solution or is there a better way solving it?

Comment: You could use PHP's URL validation instead of your own regex. See http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_url.asp. However, I think the example you gave is not a valid URL.

Comment: I think the validation isn't the problem here. I have to take the URLs like they are. They are imported from a XML file, linking to special book archives and libraries. And to validate I first have to find the URL in the text string. And that's done by the regex pattern.